# relaciones de varios modelos en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenos dias, tengo 3 modelos "Empleado", "grupo_familar"y "documentos_familiares".
Empleado tiene  una relacion one_to-many con grupo_familar y grupo_familiar una relacion one_to_many con documentos_familiares.
Al querer levantar datos de empleado me sale el error:
*undefined method `document_families' for ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
EL codigo ...*

```
#modelo empleado
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :family_groups

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :family_groups,  allow_destroy: true

    mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :copy_document, CopyDocumentUploader
end

#modelo grupo_familiar 
class FamilyGroup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee, optional: true
    has_many :document_families
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :document_families,  allow_destroy: true
end

#modelo documento_familiares
class DocumentFamily < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :family_group, optional: true
end

#en empleado controller
  def show
      @employee.family_groups # de esta forma me trae los grupos familiares con exito
      @emmployee.family_groups..document_families #me sale el error anteriormente comentado.
  end
```

La intencion es levantar los datos del empleado, del grupo familiar  y de los documentos de cada grupo familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es llamar a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :family_groups
    has_many :document_families, through: :family_groups
```

Luego simplemente llamas a:

```
@employee.document_families
```